# Run python -m in Ubuntu systemd Service

Tags: python, systemd

there:

I need to run a python module as systemd service.

the command is cd /home/bitnami/abc/ && python -m abc.abc.

at /etc/systemd/system, abc.service is like this:

```
[Unit]<br>
Description=xxxx<br>
After=syslog.target<br>
After=network.target[Service]<br>
User=ubuntu<br>
Type=simple<br>

[Service]<br>
Type=simple<br>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -m abc.abc<br>
WorkingDirectory=/home/abc/abc<br>
Restart=always<br>
StandardOutput=syslog<br>
StandardError=syslog<br>
SyslogIdentifier=helloworld<br>

[Install]<br>
WantedBy=multi-user.target<br>
<br>
when I check status
I got this
<br>
● abc.service - abc Push Notification<br>
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/abc.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)<br>
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Wed 2019-10-09 00:59:36 UTC; 4s ago<br>
  Process: 2895 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -m abc.abc (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)<br>
 Main PID: 2895 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)<br>
<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, <br>status=1/FAILURE<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Unit entered failed state.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: Stopped abc Push Notification.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Start request repeated too quickly.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: Failed to start abc Push Notification.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Unit entered failed state.<br>
Oct 09 00:59:36 ip-172-26-4-222 systemd[1]: abc.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.<br>
```

I also try to change ExecStart to

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'cd /home/bitnami/abc/ | python -m abc.abc',<br>
```

it also failed.

Could anyone give me an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you insist in writing a systemd service? Have you tried adding a new service in `crontab -e` ?

Comment: Your question is better suited at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). It's probably a `ENVIRONMENT` issue, wrap it into shell script to get the error message.

Comment: systemd service is better than crontab as this is one time loading, crontab -e is my last choice if no solution for this